# Angular router transition animations slide both left and right conditionally

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-animations

I have read this article about Router transition Animations for Angular:

https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-supercharge-your-router-transitions-using-new-animation-features-v4-3-3eb341ede6c8

And:

[Angular 2 "slide in animation" of a routed component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37909208/angular-2-slide-in-animation-of-a-routed-component)

However, this is too static. I want it to slide left **and** right depending on the order of the tab.

Is it possible to create router animations for this? Example of what I mean is below:

https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples

Look how it slides **BOTH** left **and** right very naturally depending on what tab you are on.

This has to be dynamic, because the tabs will be added at runtime.

Comment: I am wondering if you could find any solution. I am having same issue.

Comment: @Téwa Yes, I have found the solution, please read my answer and if you still need help, ask me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Today things are a bit simpler because new animation aliases exist as **:increment** and **:decrement**. Aliases have been introduced in Angular 5.

So my modified solution is:

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-workspace-container',
      templateUrl: './workspace-container.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./workspace-container.component.scss'],
      animations: [
        trigger('animRoutes', [
          transition(':increment', right),
          transition(':decrement', left),
        ]),
      ],
  })
  export class ComponentContainingRouterOutlet implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
    //... ngOnInit,ngOnDestroy

    constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute ) { }

    animationState: number;

    onActivate($event) {
      this.animationState = this.route.firstChild.snapshot.data['routeIdx'];
    }
  }
```

Call animation at router-outlet position:

```
<div [@animRoutes]="animationState">
  <router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

modify routes definition as example, look at `data: { routeIdx: X }` :

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'routeOne',
        component: ComponentOne,
        data: { routeIdx: 0 }
      },
      {
        path: 'routeTwo',
        component: ComponentTwo,
        data: { routeIdx: 1}
      },
      {
        path: 'routeThree',
        component: ComponentThree,
        data: { routeIdx: 2 }
      },
      {
        path: 'routeFour',
        component: ComponentFour,
        data: { routeIdx: 3 }
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'routeOne',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
```

And transitions are the same as in [Dolan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49590255/6804292) post:

```
const left = [
    query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', width: '100%' }), { optional: true }),
    group([
        query(':enter', [style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }), animate('.3s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))], {
            optional: true,
        }),
        query(':leave', [style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }), animate('.3s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }))], {
            optional: true,
        }),
    ]),
];

const right = [
    query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', width: '100%' }), { optional: true }),
    group([
        query(':enter', [style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }), animate('.3s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))], {
            optional: true,
        }),
        query(':leave', [style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }), animate('.3s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }))], {
            optional: true,
        }),
    ]),
];
```

Comment: If I have a route from 1 -> 2, and a route from 3 -> 2, the only option is to set 2 to something above 1 and 3, e.g. 20 right?
My approach was to compare the new route url with the history stack, and this way decide the animation. But it exposed as really complex and requires a lot more code than your approach.

Comment: Left and right transitions are in [Dolan's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49590255/6804292). I skipped it intentionaly.

Comment: Say it in your post. Help viewers

Comment: @Michal.S, Works perfect. Thank you for this solution

Comment: The problem with this transition is that it resets the scroll on the page you are leaving, thus when navigating back (back button or `location.back()`) you will end up on the top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to get this to work by "faking" the state it is in.

In the `component.html`:

```
<div [@animRoutes]="pageState">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

`pageState` is a **variable** in the `component.ts` file.

Whenever I click on a tab which I want to go right, I will set `pageState` to `right`, and same for `left`, and let **Angular** take over the rest.

**Note:** You have to create a `right` and `right1` state as a **hack**, because Angular currently does not support `right => right` state transitions!! Same applies to `left` of course.

My `@Component` annotation is below:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-workspace-container',
    templateUrl: './workspace-container.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./workspace-container.component.scss'],
    animations: [
        trigger('animRoutes', [
            transition('* => right', right),
            transition('* => left', left),
            transition('* => right1', right),
            transition('* => left1', left),
        ]),
    ],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
```

Where `left`, `left1`, `right`, `right1` are:

```
const left = [
    query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', width: '100%' }), { optional: true }),
    group([
        query(':enter', [style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }), animate('.3s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))], {
            optional: true,
        }),
        query(':leave', [style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }), animate('.3s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }))], {
            optional: true,
        }),
    ]),
];

const right = [
    query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', width: '100%' }), { optional: true }),
    group([
        query(':enter', [style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }), animate('.3s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))], {
            optional: true,
        }),
        query(':leave', [style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }), animate('.3s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }))], {
            optional: true,
        }),
    ]),
];
```

**TL;DR:** Make the state you are going to into a **variable**, so you can dynamically set the state which you wish you are going to.

Comment: what if i am keeping single animation array and changing it dynamically like:
  transition('* => *', currentAnimation) and I am updating currentAnimation value when I want to change animation type?
And what is  ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush?

Comment: @Dolan what about today? with Angular 6? could you update your answer please?

Comment: Yes it is still relevant in Angular 6, because Angular 5 to 6 does not break any of this

Answer (score 0):

Great solution from Michal.S. So I can use this also without Routechange but also on your own tab component.

If you have a custom tab control you can do it like this:

Step 1: Add the animation above

```
const left = [
  query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'absolute', width: '100%' }), { optional: true }), // or fixed
  group([
    query(':enter', [style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }), animate('.4s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))], {
      optional: true,
    }),
    query(':leave', [style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }), animate('.4s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }))], {
      optional: true,
    }),
  ]),
];

const right = [
  query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'absolute', width: '100%' }), { optional: true }),
  group([
    query(':enter', [style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }), animate('.4s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))], {
      optional: true,
    }),
    query(':leave', [style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }), animate('.4s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }))], {
      optional: true,
    }),
  ]),
];
```

Step 2: In the template add the trigger to the container of the animation items. Relative or flex positioned.

```
<div [@animStep]="currentStep">
    <app-step1 *ngIf=“currentStep === 1”></app-step1>
    <app-step2 *ngIf=“currentStep === 2”></app-step2>
    <app-step3 *ngIf=“currentStep === 3”></app-step3>
</div>
```

Step 3: Add the animation inside the Component decorator

```
// component
animations: [
  trigger('animStep', [
    transition(':increment', right),
    transition(':decrement', left),
  ]),
],
```

Step 3: Trigger change of the value

```
currentStep += 1;
```