# Angular2 Animation on Load and Page Transition

Tags: css, animation, angular, angular2-routing

Currently trying to implement some animations into my Angular2 site using ng2's built in `animations` component. So far I've been working through the Angular 2 `Developer Guide - Animations` provided in the documentation. With that though I've run into a few questions I was hoping the SO community might be able to assist in. My first question/problem I seem to be having is that the animation (from what I can tell) doesn't run on page load. It seems to run perfectly fine if I switch to a view then back to the view with the animation. This is the code I'm currently using for the animation in question (I can provide the whole component if desired):

```
animations: [
  trigger('kissState', [
    state('in', style({opacity: 1})),
    transition('void => *', [
      style({opacity: 0}),
      animate('250ms ease-in-out')
    ]),
    transition('* => void', [
      animate('250ms ease-in-out', style({opacity: 0}))
    ])
  ])
]
```

I was under the impression that the `void => *` would set my DOM element to `opacity:0` and once it entered `in` to the view it would be `opacity:1`. Another problem I seem to be having is that my navigations don't seem to be working on mobile. I haven't actually moved them to my server yet but developing locally and looking on my mobile device via node `localtunnel` there doesn't seem to be any animations. This could be because the strange way `localtunnel` operates so I'm not too terribly concerned about that until I can truly test it on an actual server. Here's the other animation that in particular is when I noticed it wasn't working on my mobile device:

```
animations: [
  trigger('offScreenMenu', [
    state('inactive', style({
      opacity: 0,
      zIndex: -10
    })),
    state('active',   style({
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
      zIndex: 10
      })),
    transition('inactive => active', animate('250ms ease-in')),
    transition('active => inactive', animate('250ms ease-out'))
  ])
]
```

One last problem I've been having which is a known issue by the Angular2 team is animations on router view change. There's currently a SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904860/angular-2-animate-no-visible-effect-of-the-void-transition-when-changin) that addresses this and a ticket on the Angular2 repo (mentioned in the comment by Günter Zöchbauer in the SO question). With that, I was curious if there were any present workarounds? Through some brief research it looked like there may at one time have been implemented a `ng-enter` and `ng-leave` one could use within their css for this, but from what I can tell these have been phased out. Still need to do a little more research so I could be wrong about that.

Thanks in advance for any help!

UPDATE(7.7.16): Alright so I decided to come back around to it and after messing with the timing of the page load animation it does appear to be working. Though I have to do a roughly a `1000ms` animation for it to be noticed. Which brings me to the questions (or more thought) that I believe the animation starts to execute before the DOM has fully loaded. Which would seem a bit strange.
Still working on the mobile animation situation. Looking like I'll be filing an issue on the Github repo at the moment as I've messed with it a fair bit and can't seem to get it to work. Also there doesn't seem to be any mention of mobile animations not working for NG2.

UPDATE(7.13.16): Looks like the Angular2 team has made a few fixes slated to release with RC5 that should address my above concerns. Going to answer my own question and close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going to close this question. Most of the issues I mentioned above look like they have been resolved in RC5 of Angular2. Looks like it'll be the waiting game until then. Here's the links to the respective issues/PRs in the Angular repo:

My hunch that elements were `animating` before page load was correct and has been resolved in this PR: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/9887

RC5 will contain a fix to allow animations on route change via this PR: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/9933 and NG2 will eventually allow a `query()` function for animations which will be great (more can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9845#issuecomment-232496175) in that regard).

As for the mobile issue. I'm still trying to figure out the a way of recreating the bug on a mobile device (i.e. - in plunker) but have been unsuccessful so far. Not a `breaking` issue for my website though so I'll be moving forward for now.

Answer (score 1):

**Angular 2 final solution**

We can use the `@routeAnimation` built-in directive to achieve this as per my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40077108/1087131) which includes a plunk.